# How to make two col-xs/sm/md/lg-6 within btn-toolbar without breaking the line?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, frontend

Here the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/VUDfp/

Two buttons `<div class="btn btn-primary col-xs-6">` **cannot fit into one line** (class `row`). I  wrapped them into the `btn-toolbar` to create spaces between them.

But now this added margin cannot fit anymore into one line since col-xx-6 is 50%.

Is there a pure `bootstrap` way (*working with classes not with pure css*) to fill the whole line with buttons (2-3 buttons for the whole width from left to right), without breaking the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Bootstrap is working with `box-sizing:border-box` your best bet is probably to wrap the buttons within the col-xs-6 class and add a left padding to every div except the first one. You will have to add a few lines of custom CSS code though to remove the left margin on the buttons. However, it will still use Bootstrap's classes as you requested.

**Check out my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VUDfp/14/**

Comment: usable :) but still a bit workaroundy, but anyway usable :) and not complex - just one class dependency. strange that bootstrap doesn't have this option